# Google app engine(java) datastore retrieve not working

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I am not able to retrieve the Entities from Data Store .

Following : [Google Code Lab](http://googcloudlabs.appspot.com/codelabexercise1.html) I made this function :

```
   @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
   public static Iterable<Entity> listEntities(String kind, String searchBy,String searchFor) {
   com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreService ds = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
   Query q = new Query(kind);

   if (searchFor != null && !"".equals(searchFor)) 
        {
            q.addFilter(searchBy, FilterOperator.EQUAL, searchFor);
        }

    PreparedQuery pq = ds.prepare(q);

    return pq.asIterable();

    }
```

then calling this to get the values :

```
    for(Entity u:listEntities("Upload","UID","ratan"))
         {
             String uid = (String) u.getProperty("url");
             System.out.println("#1##"+uid);
         }
```

But it does not prints any value !!! 
where I went wrong .

this is my Datastore instance for "Upload" Entity

[image]

Even this doesn't works:

```
for(Entity u:listEntities("Upload",null,null))
{
  String uid = (String) u.getProperty("url");
  System.out.println("#1##"+uid);
}
```

Comment: What happens when you try to fetch all "Upload" Entities? Is it possible you have white space in "ratan"?

Comment: @mconlin see my last function even that doesn't give any output .

Comment: try simply List<Entity> uploads = ds.prepare(q).asList(); and see if that returns anything? Is "Upload" the correct Entity name? Case correct? Plural correct?